# WooCommerce coupon code wildcard

Tags: woocommerce, minimum, coupon

I have my cart set with a minimum order of $15.  However, I want to create some coupon codes that will bypass the minimum order requirement.  My code below allows me to name a specific coupon.  How do I use a wildcard so that I don't have to list every coupon code I have that starts with the letters nm?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
/* add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' ); */
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
// Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
$minimum = 15;

 // No minimum purchase if a specific coupon code is used
if ( WC()->cart->has_discount ( '*nm*' ) ) {
    return;
}

if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum ) {

    if( is_cart() ) {

        wc_print_notice( 
            sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order subtotal is %s.' , 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
            ), 'error' 
        );

    } else {

        wc_add_notice( 
            sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
            ), 'error' 
        );

    }
}

}
```

The code where I want to use a wildcard is here (3rd paragraph in the code above):

```
 // No minimum purchase if a specific coupon code is used
if ( WC()->cart->has_discount ( 'nm*' ) ) {
return;
}
```

The * doesn't work.  How do I code this?  Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if cart has discount coupon applied, then loop through each coupon if there's one that starts with `nm`.

```
    // No minimum purchase if a specific coupon code is used
    if ( WC()->cart->has_discount ( ) ) { // check if has discount coupons
        // loop through each coupon
        foreach ( WC()->cart->applied_coupons as $coupon ) {
            if (strpos($coupon, 'nm') === 0) {
                // coupon starts with 'nm'
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, Reigel.  Your code works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. I'd appreciate it if you could accept the answer and up vote. Cheers! @Cindy